# System fails to boot after Linux installation

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, kali-linux, grub, boot-loader

I have installed kali linux. But when I try to boot I receive the following message as shown in the figure:

May be because of wrong GRUB configuration.
How can it be fixed?

[image: this is what i get]

Comment: nah. that's what is supposed to happen! enjoy linux!

Comment: Is this means something wrong?

Comment: no, everything's just fine. isn't it *fast*, too?

Comment: What to do to get the UI?

Comment: I mean that. I cant go further. How do i get the desktop?

Comment: Would it be too much trouble rotating the image?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - what? what's wrong with the image?

Comment: I guess, if you're quarter of the way round the world you might need it rotated

Comment: I have set the photo right .. check now

Comment: Looks like you are missing the GRUB configuration file

Answer (score 0):

If installation was done properly and completely then just boot from CD and restore/repair your grub only !

Comment: If selected grub installation. It goes into partitioning the HDD

Comment: Yes go ahead and look for option there to Install grub at MBR ! bty do you have another boot loader at MBR ? If not then install it  !